# Trouble using Fetch to grab a JSON value and output as text in html

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

I am trying to grab a value from an API and output it into my html code as text. The API link is "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company/profile/AAPL" (data is in JSON). The code below is my attempt at getting the price. My end goal is to have the user enter a stock ticker into an input box and the price for the stock to be outputted as text. I have successfully used the document.value function for returning values upon button clicks but I am not able to get it to work using an API and fetch.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pareto</title>

    <script>

    function xStockPrice(); {
        const fetch = require("node-fetch");
        
        const apiURL = "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company/profile/AAPL"

        fetch(apiUrl)
            .then((res) =>res.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data.profile.price))

        document.tickerInputForm.output.value=data.profile.price
    }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form name="tickerInputForm">
        <input type="text" name="xTicker"/>
        <input type="button" value="Get Quote" onclick="xStockPrice();"/>
        <input type="text" name="output"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have a few minor errors in your code, it should look like this:

```
function xStockPrice(); {
    const fetch = require("node-fetch");

    const apiURL = "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company/profile/AAPL"
    // Before you used apiUrl, JavaScript variables are case sensitive
    // so apiURL is not the same as apiUrl and vice versa
    fetch(apiURL)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data.profile.price);
            // Before this line lived outside of your then handler
            // Which causes two issues:
            // 1: data will be undefined, it only exists in the scope of this anonymous function
            // 2: The code will execute before your request is finished, you use then to wait for the response, so even if you had created the variable data before, it would be undefined when this line was executed, you use then to fill in the value and then you can use it to set the value of your input element
            document.tickerInputForm.output.value = data.profile.price;
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is the **semi-colon** in your function declaration `function xStockPrice();`

It should be like this:

```
function xStockPrice(){
    const fetch = require("node-fetch");

    const apiURL = "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company/profile/AAPL"

    fetch(apiURL)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data.profile.price);
            document.tickerInputForm.output.value = data.profile.price;
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

Using the `JavaScript fetch` your code works fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Pareto</title>

    <script>
      function xStockPrice() {
        // const fetch = require("node-fetch");

        const apiURL =
          "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company/profile/AAPL";
   
        fetch(apiURL)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
            console.log(data.profile.price);
           
            document.tickerInputForm.output.value = data.profile.price;
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="tickerInputForm">
      <input type="text" name="xTicker" />
      <input type="button" value="Get Quote" onclick="xStockPrice();" />
      <input type="text" name="output" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```